# Get DataFrame index by name

Tags: python, pandas

How to access one index from a multi-indexed DataFrame by its name?

For instance, I want to access the "year" index from this dataframe using the string "year" :

```
df.tail()

dayofyear  year
361        2015   -7.244481
362        2015   -7.245178
363        2015   -7.245608
364        2015   -7.245999
365        2015   -7.246563
```

Do I need o use `.reset_index`?

Comment: You mean `df.index.get_level_values('year')`?

Comment: @EdChum: yes, that's it. Convert your comment as an answer and I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query multi-indices for a specific level's values using [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html#pandas.Index.get_level_values):

```
In [163]:
df.index.get_level_values('year')

Out[163]:
Int64Index([2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015], dtype='int64', name='year')
```

This accepts either the ordinal position or the level string value